# Java implementation of SHA-1 without external libraries

Tags: java

How can you use a message digest algorithm in Java (e.g. *SHA-1*) without using an external library.

Comment: This is a seriously lame question.  Did you do any research before posting this?  Did you look at e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1#SHA-1_pseudocode?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Listtheavailablealgorithmnamesforcipherskeyagreementmacsmessagedigestsandsignatures.htm

Answer (score 4):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html:

> Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the
>   following standard MessageDigest algorithms:
>
> - MD5
> - SHA-1
> - SHA-256

Answer (score 2):

```
String message = "This is a test Message";
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
System.out.println(calculateHash(sha1, message));

public static String calculateHash(MessageDigest algorithm,
        String message) throws Exception{
    algorithm.update(message.getBytes());
    byte[] hash = algorithm.digest();
    return byteArray2Hex(hash);
}
```